# redux-persist does't work, rehydrate only occur once

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, frontend

I am currently working with react 15.4.2 and redux, i am going to keep my react/redux state whenever the browser refresh. and i found people are suggesting redux-persist but when i follow the instruction of basic usage, it doesn't work at all, all state returning to empty again when i refresh my browser. this is what shown by logger 
[image]

rehydrate only show once (at the first time ), and never happen again while doing another action. and here is my store.js

```
import {createStore, applyMiddleware} from "redux";
import thunk from "redux-thunk";
import logger from "redux-logger";
import promise from "redux-promise-middleware";
import {composeWithDevTools} from "redux-devtools-extension";
import {autoRehydrate, persistStore} from 'redux-persist';

import combineReducer from "./reducers/combineReducer";

const middleware = composeWithDevTools(applyMiddleware(promise(), thunk, logger()), autoRehydrate());

const store = createStore(combineReducer, middleware);
persistStore(store);

export default store;
```

and here is my index.js :

```
import React from "react";
import ReacrDOM from "react-dom";
import {Router, Route, IndexRoute, hashHistory, browserHistory} from "react-router"
import {Provider} from "react-redux";
import {login_check} from "./actions/logActions";

import store from "./store";
import Layout from "./pages/Layout";
import Dashboard from "./pages/Dashboard";
import Login from "./pages/login/index";
import User from "./pages/user/index";
import Pemain from "./pages/pemain/index";

const app = document.getElementById("app");

function requireLogin() {
    const {user_id, session_key}=store.getState().logReducer;
    store.dispatch(login_check({user_id: user_id, session_key: session_key}))
    const {logged_in}=store.getState().logReducer;
    if (!logged_in) {
        /*browserHistory.push('#/login');*/
        hashHistory.push('/login');
    }
}

ReacrDOM.render(
    <Provider store={store}>
        <Router history={hashHistory}>
            <Route path="/login" component={Login}/>
            <Route path="/" component={Layout} onEnter={requireLogin}>
                <IndexRoute component={Dashboard} onEnter={requireLogin}/>
                <Route path="user" component={User} onEnter={requireLogin}/>
                <Route path="pemain" component={Pemain} onEnter={requireLogin}/>
            </Route>
        </Router>
    </Provider>
    , app);
```

and here is package.json :

```
{
  "name": "learn-react",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "for learning purpose only",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1",
    "dev": "webpack-dev-server --content-base --inline --hot --port 3300"
  },
  "keywords": [
    "react",
    "learning"
  ],
  "author": "vidy hermes",
  "license": "ISC",
  "devDependencies": {
    "webpack": "^2.2.1",
    "webpack-dev-server": "^2.3.0",
    "redux-devtools-extension": "^2.13.0",
    "redux-logger": "^2.8.1"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "axios": "^0.15.3",
    "babel-core": "^6.22.1",
    "babel-loader": "^6.2.10",
    "babel-plugin-react-html-attrs": "^2.0.0",
    "babel-plugin-transform-class-properties": "^6.22.0",
    "babel-plugin-transform-decorators-legacy": "^1.3.4",
    "babel-preset-es2015": "^6.22.0",
    "babel-preset-react": "^6.22.0",
    "babel-preset-stage-0": "^6.22.0",
    "base-64": "^0.1.0",
    "css-loader": "^0.26.2",
    "file-loader": "^0.10.1",
    "globalize": "^0.1.1",
    "history": "^4.5.1",
    "less": "^2.7.2",
    "less-loader": "^2.2.3",
    "moment": "^2.17.1",
    "path": "^0.12.7",
    "react": "15.4.2",
    "react-dom": "15.4.2",
    "react-redux": "^5.0.2",
    "react-redux-loading-bar": "^2.8.2",
    "react-router": "^3.0.2",
    "react-widgets": "^3.4.6",
    "redux": "^3.6.0",
    "redux-persist": "^4.8.0",
    "redux-promise-middleware": "^4.2.0",
    "redux-thunk": "^2.2.0",
    "style-loader": "^0.13.2",
    "url-loader": "^0.5.8"
  }
}
```

i have google it for two days, and still haven't found any solution, how to make react-persist work? please kindly help me..

regards,

vidy hermes

Comment: haven't found any solution yet, but i try to look for another solution for the main problem, which is redux state persistency , so i am currently using redux-localstorage, it is quite easy to set up and it work well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you need to pass autorehydrate to createStore not composeWithDevTools

```
import { autoRehydrate } from 'redux-persist';
import { createStore } from 'redux';
import thunk from 'redux-thunk';
import logger from 'redux-logger'

const middleware = composeWithDevTools(applyMiddleware(promise(), thunk, logger()));

const store = createStore(combineReducer, middleware, autoRehydrate());
```

Comment: still does not work, state being reset every time i refresh the page.. but thank you

Answer (score 0):

i am just a novice in react/redux . though i didnt import the promise and thunk , i just used the normal syntax i guess you are using the " () " after logger that makes it a function call and it doesnt save the state and autoRehydrate in the store.

```
using composeWithDevTools:

const middleware = composeWithDevTools(applyMiddleware(logger));

 let store = createStore(rootReducer   , middleware , autoRehydrate());
 persistStore(store ) ;

using simple boilerplate :

let store = createStore(rootReducer   , applyMiddleware(logger) , autoRehydrate());
 persistStore(store ) ;
```

I hope it helps .